# C# DataBinding tutorial

Tags: c#, wpf

Does anyone know a good data binding tutorial for beginners? I'm trying to get it to work for the last few hours and my head is spinning already.. Is there any simple tutorials, WITHOUT unnecessary code where is shown how just bind property to a variable and something like that?

Comment: You really should read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), it's long but data binding is not simple so that is necessary and if you understand all of that you will have less trouble later on.

Comment: Sigh, yet another crucial newbie question closed as off-topic.

Comment: agreed, just reopen it because many people have the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_3.aspx) article, code samples in it seem pretty small and straight forward.  Though if you're having specific issues, you should post those as questions and someone will help you figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Definitely something that's very, very useful!

Comment: Well yes, but there are no examples :(

Answer (score 3):

I spent a long time trying to understand how to even do the most simple of binding... the syntax just didn't make any sense to me. When I finally stumbled across this tutorial, it felt like a light bulb suddenly turned on. Extremely simple, step-by-step explanations helped me understand the relation between the visual element and the code-behind.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/simple-data-binding-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

Some samples with that focus are here:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#databinding