# WPF Custom Button and Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application. I have created a custom style of button. The button contains a textbox & two images. I have created the style in my App.xaml file. The question I have is this. I want to create a number of buttons in my MainWindow.xaml file that will use the style from my App.xaml. This works but now I wish to bind the images & textbox to a element in list object called Securities.

So when create a button in my MainWindow how do I set the binding for the textbox & images?

```
 <!-- style for button -->
    <Style x:Key="buttSecurity" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                    
                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource brushSecurityButtRadial}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource txtSecurity}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>               
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807006/c-sharp-databinding-tutorial

Comment: You're not going to change or delete your question again when you've got an answer are you?

Comment: I didn't change my last question. I understand your point that I gave credit to the wrong answer & have since updated it. I have never deleted my questions not sure where your getting that from?

Comment: Just checking before I take the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want directly. The way to achieve that functionality is to put your `ControlTemplate` and `Style` into a `UserControl` and then add three `DependencyProperty`s to bind to:

```
    <Style x:Key="buttSecurity" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                    
                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource brushSecurityButtRadial}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style=
"{StaticResource txtSecurity}" Text="{Binding TextValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourButtonUserControl}}}" />
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding 
ImageSource1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourButtonUserControl}}}" />
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding 
ImageSource2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourButtonUserControl}}}" />
                    </Grid>               
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Assuming that you have an `Images` folder, you would then use the `UserControl` like this:

```
<YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourButtonUserControl TextValue="Click me" 
    ImageSource1="/AppName;component/Images/Image1.jpg" 
    ImageSource1="/AppName;component/Images/Image2.jpg" />
```

I won't bother showing you how to declare a `DependencyProperty` as there are loads of resource on that to be found online.

Answer (score 0):

Try TemplateBinding

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="buttSecurity" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Background="Red">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        **<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>**
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding MyText}" Style="{StaticResource buttSecurity}"/>
```